# How to make magento price reindexing and catalog rule apply process faster?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, reindex

I am using Magento Community Edition **1.9.2.**4.

Its a **multi-store-webiste** with **9 websites** and **25 store** views. At present the **price re-indexing is taking 40 minutes**.

This causing issue when I apply **catalog price rules**. It's taking very long time to complete rule apply process. At present, rule apply process is taking 30 Min's (if there 10 rules) and 40 - 50 minutes for price re-indexing (**every time catalog rule apply happens price re-indexing will start automatically**) Around 1.5 hours in total.

If I want to show a set of quick promotions on website, I need to wait so much time to see it on website. Is there any solution for this. ? I can't use cart rule instead of catalog.

Answer (score 3):

By clicking “**Save and apply**” Mаgentо **rewrites all existing rules**

`applyRules()` is called during the function of `saveAction()` of the controller `Mage_Adminhtml_Promo_CatalogController`.

**Instead of rewriting all rules, recalculates only that one which has been edited.**

Find [Module](https://github.com/belvg-public/SmartyApplyCatalogRule)

Source : https://belvg.com/blog/catalog-price-rule-optimization.html

Another solution : https://belvg.com/blog/optimizing-complex-processes-as-illustrated-by-magento-catalog-price-rules.html

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing these information's. but how we can optimize the price re-indexing process. because that's the one taking lots of time to complete. until price re-indexing complete, discounted price won't show correctly.

Comment: @JicksonJohnsonKoottala try to reindex using command line.  `php indexer.php --reindexall` after applying rule